# Are there Covid-19 death maps locally adjusted for population density?

Tags: covid-19, comparative-politics, reference-request, public-health

As a first motivating example, according to an Oxford CEBM [map](https://www.cebm.net/covid-19/covid-19-global-charts-of-deaths-and-cases/) [even] Sweden has more deaths *per capita* from Covid-19 (217 deaths/mil.pop.) than the US as a whole (166 deaths/mil.p.) On top of that, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population_density) the US has higher population density (34 per km<sup>2</sup>) than Sweden (23 per km<sup>2</sup>). So in that view, Sweden is doing "doubly worse" worse (320 = 217 * 34/23) than the US.

As another data point, Spain for example has 496 deaths/mil.pop. but their population density is 93 per km<sup>2</sup>. So that makes Spain seen closer to the US--their number would roughly be a third (181 = 496 * 34/93) if (crudely) adjusted by population density to compared to the US.

For Italy, their population density is twice that of Spain (200 per km<sup>2</sup>) and their deaths per mil.pop. (441) are even less than Spain's. So that makes Italy look good in comparison to Spain in this view. Even compared to the US, Italy fares better (75 = 441 * 34/200) in this perspective.

My calculations are fairly crude adjustments though, ignoring the fact that within countries (esp. US or Sweden) there are large internal variations in population density. So are there some studies/maps that plot **the local Covid-19 death rate relative to the local population density** (worldwide)? (Of course one needs to do some clustering to produce such maps, so I'm leaving fairly open-ended what "local" means.)

As more motivation for this q, I found [a paper on the 1918-1919 flu](https://hal.sorbonne-universite.fr/hal-01905736/document) deaths (per capita) vs population density (in the US):

> Investigations of possible links between population density and the propagation and
>   magnitude of epidemics have so far proved inconclusive. There are three possible
>   reasons (i) A lack of focus on appropriate density intervals. (ii) For the density to be
>   a meaningful variable the population must be distributed as uniformly as possible. If
>   an area has towns and cities where a majority of the population is concentrated its
>   average density is meaningless. [...] Here we show that when these requirements are properly accounted for, the size
>   of epidemics is indeed closely connected with the population density.
>
> [image]
>
> Relationship between population density d and the size µ of the influenza epidemic of September-December 1918. In the graph m means million. The data are for Indiana, Kansas and the city of Philadelphia
>   in Pennsylvania. Influenza and pneumonia deaths are counted together. It can be seen that the relationship
>   between population density holds only on a broad density scale. Inside of the three groups of data points the
>   background fluctuations are strong enough to override the power law. The regression reads (the confidence
>   interval is for a confidence probability of 0.95): µ = Cd<sup>α</sup>, α = 0.22 ± 0.08, C = 3.5. Source: Bureau of the
>   Census (1920).

So yeah, the correction for pop density should probably be on a power law, not (linearly) how I've done it in the first part of my question. Doing this (power law correction) instead however, would "disadvantage" the low-density areas/countries even more than how I've done it in the first half of my question!

So, to repeat my question: are there any published models/maps of this kind (adjusting the death rate for population density) for Covid-19?

Comment: @divibisan: contagious diseases spread easier in areas with higher population density (although there may be a ceiling effect). And yes, pop density has been considered in peer-reviewed publications on such models e.g. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mbs.2013.04.013

Comment: the problem is that the average population density doesn't mean all that much.  what you want is something like a median population density instead.  Canada for example has a low population density, but a lot of people do live in big cities, especially in BC.  there are lots of places like that, where most of the population is clustered in a few cities and the rest of the country is fairly unpopulated.  those look like low density countries, but each person is likely to be living in close proximity to a lot of other people

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: I agree, my correction is pretty crude, that's why I'm asking for better models.

Comment: @divibisan: Even the CDC reckons that's a factor: "Geographic differences in numbers of COVID-19 cases and deaths, cumulative incidence, and changes in incidence likely reflect a combination of jurisdiction-specific epidemiologic and population-level factors, including 1) the timing of COVID-19 introductions; 2) population density; 3) age distribution and prevalence of underlying medical conditions among COVID-19 patients (1–3); 4) the timing and extent of community mitigation measures; 5) diagnostic testing capacity; and 6) public health reporting practices."

Comment: That's after they note "Cumulative COVID-19 incidence varied substantially by jurisdiction, ranging from 20.6 cases per 100,000 in Minnesota to 915.3 in NYC." https://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/volumes/69/wr/mm6915e4.htm

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: https://ggwash.org/view/65370/median-versus-average-population-density

Comment: @Fizz yup, I'd seen that article before.  see also https://www.citymetric.com/fabric/these-maps-reveal-truth-about-population-density-across-europe-3625  trouble is that no one seems to have published a robust world statistic for this.  whenever I look for median density I end up with std average density metrics.  or articles calculating it one way or another for a few places.  Maybe [urbanization rates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urbanization_by_country)?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: "Investigations of possible links between population density and the propagation and magnitude of epidemics have so far proved inconclusive. There are three possible reasons (i) A lack of focus on appropriate density intervals. (ii) For the density to be a meaningful variable the population must be distributed as uniformly as possible. If an area has towns and cities where a majority of the population is concentrated its average density is meaningless." https://hal.sorbonne-universite.fr/hal-01905736/document

Comment: @Italian Philosophers 4 Monica: Of course an obvious point is that the hardest-hit area (currently), the New York City metro area, also has probably the highest population density in the US.  But outside of NYC and the Buffalo & Rochester areas, both fairly high density, the state doesn't seem to have that many cases: https://www.syracuse.com/coronavirus/2020/04/where-is-coronavirus-in-ny-see-map-charts-of-covid-19-cases-deaths-hospitalizations-saturday-april-25.html  In a way, this seems obvious: it spreads from person to person, so if you don't come close to many people, your odds are low.

Comment: not deaths, but the RKI [German CDC] maps at https://corona.rki.de give case numbers per 100k population (on Länder [≈state]/Kreis [≈county] level). Not much of a connection there (and probably even less for the deaths: they are right now driven by outbreaks in nursing homes, also in rural areas). I saw a graph with incidence (or cases?) over population density some weeks ago but couldn't find it right now. It did not reveal any relation. Possible factors: strong regional dependence, if public transit poses higher risk, then lower population Kreise surrounding big cities are at high risk.

Comment: ... and none of the events nor skiing holidays that were responsible for large spread are tied to high population density.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX: yeah, I suspect pop density doesn't matter much until you get true (uncontrolled) community transmission. But still pop density could correlate with the number of nursing homes and/or the number of their residents in area etc. And yes, the super-spreader events don't necessarily have to be correlated with pop density, iff the population respects some kind of social distancing measures. Otherwise, I [strongly] doubt they are uncorrelated.

Comment: @Fizz: of course it could, but for Germany, I'd expect that the number of nursing home places *roughly* goes with the general population density (afaik the East has older population - but they have less cases / 100k pop: no carnival etc. and if skiing holidays in the Alps, they were just that bit earlier). Still, if the deaths we see occur in sporadic clusters such as nursing homes (there's also an infamous hospital outbreak) no obvious ties to population density shouldn't be too surprising. And, e.g. people commute into Frankfurt from as far as 100 km away, probably the same for Munich, ...

Comment: ... Stuttgart, ... (less for Berlin and other big cities in the East). But for the West and South of Germany that covers a huge chunk of the population. And you can have a Berlin club spreading event just like Tirschenreuth strong beer festival or Heinsberg carnival (there are tons of little carnival meetings in villages or small towns, not just the big ones in Cologne, Mainz, ... - Heinsberg was the unlucky one).

Comment: Not sure density is a great metric, either, without more information, because the USA has both vast expanses of sparsely populated areas as well as higher density cities, while other nations with less land area may not have as wide a range.  You might have two nations with similar densities, overall, but a very different dynamic going on.  But who said we have to have a simple explanation for a complex issue?

Comment: @cbeleites unhappy with SX: Ever been to a downhill ski resort on a holiday weekend?  VERY high density in those places.

Comment: @jamesqf: sure, that's how the disease spread (though it's maybe less the population density of Ischgl at the height of the season then the population density in the Ischgl Après-Ski bars in the evenings, which I'd rather classify with the events). But AFAIK, those who got after contracting it there are counted at their homes (and were spreading it further there). And those homes are all over the place in Southern Germany, it's not only urban elites that go skiing in the Alps, lots of people living in rural Southern Germany do that as well.

Comment: @cbeleites unhappy with SX: Sure.  I'm really using "population density" as shorthand for "situations where there is a lot of close contact between significant numbers of people".  And in the case of ski resorts and such, a continually changing population, too, as people come for days or weeks, mingle in crowded lounges and apres-ski activities, then return to their homes.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/covid-19-death-rate-vs-population-density) is not quite a map, but a scatter plot of *log* deaths/pop vs pop. density. The US is the red dot next to "North America" and Sweden (USA label doesn't show for some reason unless you hover over it in the interactive version)

[image]

I'll accept a better answer that does go to a more local (i.e. below-country) level.

I [found](https://www.citylab.com/equity/2020/04/coronavirus-spread-map-city-urban-density-suburbs-rural-data/609394/) some data for the US like that (i.e. below country-level), but aggregated by county type (with a non-obvious figure of actual pop density), and it's also pretty dated (~1 month old by now):

[image]

> As to the question of density itself: Kolko’s analysis finds density to be significantly associated with Covid-19 deaths across U.S. counties. But density is not the only factor at play. His analysis also finds that Covid-19 death rates per capita are higher in counties with older populations and larger shares of minorities, and colder, wetter climates. It’s important to remember that this analysis only looks at the U.S., and in other parts of the world, denser cities have had more success controlling the spread.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering about Mongolia, it probably doesn't appear because it has had zero deaths, which doesn't compute with log graphs.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: well, a lot of the third world countries probably have under-reported deaths from Covid-19 (due to not enough testing), so one should probably not try to infer too much from such cross-country comparisons between countries with vastly different GPD/capita etc. In the "column" (vertical band) that US and Sweden form in that scatter plot you also have Angola etc.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: another (3rd world) outlier: Burundi, with 1x-2x the pop density of Italy (sources don't even agree much on the pop density in Burundi...). Burundi apparently has 1 death reported.

Comment: Is it just me or is the dot on the scatter plot representing the USA not labelled? I'm guessing logically it's the orange one to the right of the North American average.